# Extracting id from a url

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract id from a url, below my code:

```
$text = '/news/35555555555-title-of-the-article';
$text = eregi("news/(.*)-",$text,$regs); 
echo $regs[1];
```

I want to echo only

```
35555555555
```

but above code is printing:

```
35555555555-title-of-the
```

Comment: `preg_match("~news/(.*?)-~i",$text,$regs)` or `"~news/([^-]+)~i"`  or `"~news/\K[^-]+~i"`.

Comment: `eregi()`: **Warning** This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a character class that excludes the hyphen instead of the dot that matches any character. `ereg*` functions use the POSIX syntax and don't have non-greedy quantifiers:

```
$text = '/news/35555555555-title-of-the-article';
$text = eregi("news/([^-]*)-",$text,$regs); 
echo $regs[1];
```

Note that `ereg*` functions are deprecated since php 5.3 and produce a warning until the 5.6 versions included. They have been removed since php 7.0 and produce a fatal error. However, `mb_ereg*` functions are always available. Note also that php 5.2 is no more supported since Jan 2011 (in other words, you have to upgrade your php version).

Instead, use the `preg_*` functions that use the backtracking engine with a Perl-like syntax (with non-greedy quantifiers in particular):

```
$text = '/news/35555555555-title-of-the-article';
preg_match('~/news/(.*?)-~', $text, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Without regex, you can use a formatted string:

```
$text = '/news/35555555555-title-of-the-article';
list ($id) = sscanf(strtolower($text), '/news/%[^-]-');
echo $id;
```

or more common string functions:

```
$text = '/news/035555555555-title-of-the-article';
list($id,) = explode('-', substr(strrchr($text, '/'), 1)); 
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The dirty but easy way is

```
$text = '/news/35555555555-title-of-the-article';
$parts = end(explode('/', $text));
$param = explode('-', $parts);
echo $param[0];
```